# issue with custom label

Tags: core-plot

I think i found a bug similar to issue 104

I have a bar graph. My axis is fixed with constraint and i use padding left on my plot area and custom label for my X axis.

It is import to show the last bars so my xRange starts on the end with the code below

```
plotSpace.xRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromFloat([[posicoes lastObject] floatValue]) length:CPTDecimalFromFloat(tipoEscalaGrafico*60*13)];
```

Everything works perfectly except from the label.

On the print bellow you can see the problem

http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-BLWrnrZ1MZY/T8aMqEc3PzI/AAAAAAAAAG8/sXhIgvuuj_0/s1600/Captura+de+Tela+2012-05-30+às+18.05.01.png

The label doesn't respect the padding.

If i scroll the graph then it respect the padding as the screen bellow

http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-uvFem8xERAo/T8aMmaLRl2I/AAAAAAAAAG0/DZx_UwCcmbA/s1600/Captura+de+Tela+2012-05-30+às+18.05.01+(2).png

Comment: How did you set up the custom label?

Answer (score 0):

I have a class that inherits from CPTXYGraph and i did the method below to add custom labl=els

```
-(void)setarLabelsEixoX:(NSArray *)labels naPosicao:(NSArray *)posicaoLabels;{
CPTXYAxisSet *axisSet = (CPTXYAxisSet *)self.axisSet;
CPTXYAxis *x          = axisSet.xAxis;

x.labelingPolicy = CPTAxisLabelingPolicyNone;
NSUInteger labelLocation     = 0;
NSMutableArray *customLabels = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:[labels count]];
for ( NSNumber *tickLocation in posicaoLabels ) {
    CPTAxisLabel *newLabel = [[CPTAxisLabel alloc] initWithText:[labels objectAtIndex:labelLocation++] textStyle:x.labelTextStyle];
    newLabel.tickLocation = [tickLocation decimalValue];
    newLabel.offset       = x.labelOffset; 
    newLabel.alignment = CPTAlignmentCenter;
    [customLabels addObject:newLabel];        
}

axisSet.xAxis.majorTickLocations = (NSSet*)posicaoLabels;
x.axisLabels = [NSSet setWithArray:customLabels];
```

}

Comment: Is `posicaoLabels` an array or a set? I don't think you can cast one to the other type.

Answer (score 0):

I did a little testing with the latest Core Plot code. I don't see an issue. Did you verify that the tick location of the errant label was actually outside the plot range? What version of Core Plot are you using?

Comment: Yes, as you can see on the print, the tick location for value "16" is outside of the plot range because i set some padding left space. I am using version 1.0 . Could you please send me your testing project? so i can check to see what i am doing wrong.

Comment: Add the following statement to the Labeling Policy Demo in the Plot Gallery app: `plotSpace.allowsUserInteraction = YES;`. I experimented with the label location, starting labels outside the axis range on both ends and it worked as expected.